# Order by number of matching words

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I wrote down a query but it don't fully matching my needs. 
I want to get all the rows that contain a list of words and order it by the number of these words found in the string.

Here's my data example :

```
+--------+------------------------------+
| ITM_ID |           ITM_Name           |
+--------+------------------------------+
|      1 | Blue Shirt with white collar |
|      2 | Party dress                  |
|      3 | Black derbies with cap toe   |
|      4 | Sky blue dress               |
+--------+------------------------------+
```

If I search with the words "blue" and "dress", I want the following results :

```
+---+------------------------------+
| 4 | Sky blue dress               |
| 1 | Blue Shirt with white collar |
| 2 | Party dress                  |
+---+------------------------------+
```

The "Sky blue dress" is on top of the list because we find both of the words instead of only one in the other strings.

I figured out how to search the words with `CONTAINS` :

```
SELECT ITM_ID, ITM_Name, CHARINDEX(
FROM T_Item_ITM
WHERE CONTAINS(ITM_Name, 'dress OR blue')
```

But I don't find a solution for the order. Do you have one ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can a word appear more than once in a string, e.g. "out" in "Out, damned spot! Out, I say!"? Does that affect the ranking?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server is your target version?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string_split` to isolate single words, and then `group by` to count them.

```
declare @tmp table (ITM_ID int ,  ITM_Name nvarchar(100))
insert @tmp values
     (1 ,'Blue Shirt with white collar')
    ,(2 ,'Party dress')
    ,(3 ,'Black derbies with cap toe')
    ,(4 ,'Sky blue dress')

select a.*
from (
    select t.ITM_ID
        ,count(*) as result_count
    from @tmp t
    cross apply string_split(ITM_Name, ' ') w
    where w.[value] in (
            'blue'
            ,'dress'
            )
    group by ITM_ID
    ) c
inner join @tmp a
    on a.ITM_ID = c.ITM_ID
order by c.result_count desc
```

Results:

[image]

Please note that if you have additional punctuation (commas, semicolons and so on) you'll have to replace them with space before splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (
    Id INT,
    Name VARCHAR(100)
);
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
    (1, 'Blue Shirt with white collar'),
    (2, 'Party dress'),
    (3, 'Black derbies with cap toe'),
    (4, 'Sky blue dress');

DECLARE @Terms TABLE (
    Value VARCHAR(100)
);
INSERT INTO @Terms VALUES 
    ('dress'),
    ('blue');

WITH TermOccurrences AS (
    SELECT *, (LEN(d.Name) - LEN(REPLACE(d.Name, t.Value, ''))) / LEN(t.Value) AS NumOccurrences
    FROM @Data d
        INNER JOIN @Terms t ON d.[Name] LIKE '%' + t.Value + '%'
), TotalOccurrences AS (
    SELECT Id, SUM(NumOccurrences) AS TotalMatches
    FROM TermOccurrences
    GROUP BY Id
)
SELECT d.Id, d.Name, tot.TotalMatches
FROM TotalOccurrences tot
    INNER JOIN @Data d ON d.Id = tot.Id
ORDER BY tot.TotalMatches DESC
```

This checks the number of occurrences of a term by replacing the term with an empty string, and comparing the length of the original name to the length of the name without the term.

I can't speak to the performance of this, but it's a different approach that you can try.